# 404 Error on Tomcat Server even when the WAR file is in the right folder

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, devops

I am new to maven and building Java projects. So I built a Java project using Maven and copied the WAR file in the webapps folder. The file name is "print" and I copied it in the webapps located at: **/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps**

When I tried to open: http://localhost:8080/print/, I got an HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error.

The path is available in the Tomcat Web Application Manager:
[image]

The path is available in the Tomcat Web Application Manager:

I tried following some of the guides available here but nothing worked for me. Not sure what's the issue.

**Following is pom.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.springhow.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>hello-world</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks more like a wrong export to me. Your project doen't have a display name. Can you provide your `web.xml` and make sure it is included in the export?

Comment: You could also try to upload your `.war` file directly to the manager website instead of copying it to the folder. But not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: Hi @Japhei, I tried uploading the file directly but that didn't work. I have updated the question with the pom.xml code.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is your project working when started in the IDE?

Comment: @Japhei I am currently not using any IDE. This was a sample project I downloaded from Github to build and deploy on tomcat.

Comment: Ok, my guess is that all the web data was not exported. You probably don't have a `web.xml` file in your exported `.war` file. A default `web.xml` file should look like this: https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/01_w03/828227/eclipse-web-xml-source.png . It contains the display name that is not shown by your tomcat. 
In summary I guess you only exported the java code and not the web (e.g. jsp, html, ...) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a change for tomcat from version 10 onwards where they started supporting jakarta servlet and are migrating from javax.
So I suspect your war will need to be migrated first. For that they have already provided a set of guidelines which you can read about on their official pages.

For now ,

1. you can try creating a folder called webapps-javaee parallel to webapps folder.
2. Copy your war file to this directory.
3. Delete the war file and the inflated folders out of war files from webapps directory
4. Start the application again.
   You will notice that it takes slightly more time for the application to come up.
   Hopefully, this should solve your problem as it did mine.

Comment: Roh I will give you 1000 plusses now if it is possible. It solve my problem as well.

Comment: @Stojan Glad to know this helped. :)